# On/Off Button - Return True/False value with PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

Using this guide to create a "button switch" like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

What I would like to know, is how can I return a true or false value from this switch in PHP? So for example, I could use this switch like:

```
if( $button_value == true ) {
// do this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a name to the `<input>` element. If the button is checked, `$_POST['name']` will be set in the PHP script when you submit the form.

So the HTML should be:

```
<!-- Rectangular switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Then the PHP will be:

```
if (isset($_POST['switch'])) {
    // do this
}
```